# Is there a way to omit data points in a plot if it has an error value in a separate list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

To make it as simple as possible, I am trying to plot rate versus time for data from a .DAT file. I am plotting points every 10 minutes for a 24 hour period. Because of how the data file is formatted and my implementation, the time data is a list of strings.

I have a separate list that gives an error value for each instance of the rate. If the error != 0, I want to omit the rate point from the graph but keep the x-axis for time the same.

So far, I can only think of appending the list of rate and time values under an if statement saying:

```
for line in file:
    columns = line.split()

    #throws out all instances of 0 in specified column
    if(int(columns[5]) == 0:

        hhmmss.append(str(columns[1]))
        lv0rate.append(float(columns[3]))
        error.append(int(columns[5]))
```

However, this results in my x-axis being "squished" for the points that are erroneous, and I want the x-axis to remain consistent for the 24 hour time period.

I am plotting this over a 3x3 grid of subplots, so my controlling functions for the setup of the figure looks like this:

```
# plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 3)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, wspace=0.6)
make_plot(axs)

# alignment of axes
fig.align_ylabels(axs[:, 1])

# set the x major locator
for axi in axs.flat:
    axi.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(30))
fig

for axs in fig.axes:
    plt.sca(axs)
    plt.xticks(rotation=70)

plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The x-axis is being "squished" because they are strings, and there is no concept of distance between the x-values, you need to convert the `hhmmss` to datetime object:

```
import pandas as pd

hhmmss = ['00:00:00', '01:00:00', '02:00:00', '05:00:00']
hhmmss_time = [pd.Timestamp(time) for time in hhmmss]
print(hhmmss_time)

# Timestamp('2020-04-12 00:00:00'),
# Timestamp('2020-04-12 01:00:00'),
# ...
```

You would plot using `hhmmss_time` as it is a `Timestamp` object, but as you can see it assigns the current date to the time, however, you can use formatter options from matplotlib to display only the time information

```
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

# ...

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
```

An example using dummy data would be (note that there is no value for `03:00:00` nor `04:00:00`):

```
y = np.linspace(0,3,4)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
ax.plot(hhmmss_time, y)
```

[image]

Comment: When setting up hhmmss_time, it seems to read my hhmmss wrong. My hhmmss is a list of times without colons, as in it looks like [000000, 001000, 002000, ... , 235000]. When I print the timestamp, it looks like Timestamp('19-01-01 00:00:00.000001'). Do you have any advice? I cannot seem to figure it out

Comment: If you have an specific format, use `hhmmss_time = [pd.to_datetime(time, format='%H%M%S') for time in hhmmss]`, Timestamps and datetime objects will always include a date part, that is why you configure matplotlib to only display time part.

Comment: Ah I see I was implementing it wrong, but you helped me see what I was doing. Thank you very much, it worked!